# Diferencia de poner dos clases en css juntas o separadas en una declaracion

Tags: css

soy diseñador gráfico, y llevo un tiempo estudiando `html` y `css` para luego saltar a `js`.

Al estudiar clases css me ha asaltado una duda:

```
.prueba.grande {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.cuerpo .mayusculas {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

En el la primera declarion CSS si pongo dos clases por ejemplo como estan, seguidas, ¿quiere decir que solo se le aplicara ese estilo a los elementos que tengas necesariamente las dos clases?

Y en la segunda declaración, puede ser que lo que estoy diciendo es que busque los elementos con clase "cuerpo" y que todos los descendestes con clase "mayusculas" tengan ese estilo?¿

No tengo la clara la diferencia entre poner juntas o separadas los clases, dos id, tras varias pruebas en Atom, creo que debe ser algo parecido a lo que explico, pero no lo tengo claro, gracias!!!

Comment: te dejo las referencias de CSS de MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Referencia_CSS espero te ayude, principalmente en la parte de selectores

Comment: Muy buenas respuestas también tenía esa inquietud pero me fueron muy útiles sus respuestas.
Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cuando se hace de esta forma (junto, sin el espacio):

```
.prueba.grande{
     /*atributos*/
 }
```

Se hace referencia al elemento `.prueba` que tiene también la clase `.grande`.

Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="prueba grande">
    <h1></h1>
</div>
```

---

Cuando es de esta forma (con el espacio):

```
.prueba .grande{
     /*atributos*/
 }
```

Se hace referencia a cualquier descendiente del elemento `.prueba` que tenga la clase `.grande`.

Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="prueba">
    <span>
        <h1 class="grande"></h1>
   </span>
</div>
```

A continuación pongo un fiddle para ver la diferencia:

```css
.prueba.grande {
  color: red;
}
.prueba .grande {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="prueba grande">
  <h1>hola</h1>
</div>
<div class="prueba">
  <span>
        <h1 class="grande">hola</h1>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: estas equivocado en el primer ejemplo ejecutalo en un snipet

Comment: @JuankGlezz, gracias. Ya lo he corregido

Comment: Genial, mil gracias, entonces mis pruebas estaban en lo cierto, he preferido investigar y luego preguntar, para asi aprender, o intentarlo por lo menos.

Comment: nada como prueba y error para experimentar y aprender.

Answer (score 5):

> En el la primera declaracion CSS si pongo dos clases por ejemplo como están, seguidas, ¿quiere decir que solo se le aplicara ese estilo a los elementos que tengas necesariamente las dos clases?

**R:** Estas en lo correcto

Al aplicar esa regla `.prueba.grande {...}` estas diciendo que únicamente aplicara al contenido que tenga como clase `prueba` y `grande` ejemplo:

```css
.prueba.grande {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="prueba grande">aquí si aplica</div>

<div class="prueba">
  <div class="grande">aquí no aplica</div>
</div>

<div class="otra_clase">
  <div class="prueba grande">Si aplica
    <div class="otra"> y en este tambien</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Y en la segunda declaración, puede ser que lo que estoy diciendo es que busque los elementos con clase "cuerpo" y que todos los descendientes con clase "mayúsculas" tengan ese estilo?

**R:** También estas en lo correcto.

Aunque muy confuso en tu pregunta y tu concepto, pero si busca los elementos con la clase `cuerpo` y dentro de este elemento debe haber un elemento con la clase `mayúsculas` (no es que por fuerza lo deban tener). ejemplo:

```css
.cuerpo .mayusculas {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="cuerpo mayusculas">aquí no aplica</div>

<div class="cuerpo">
  <div class="mayusculas">aquí si aplica</div>
</div>

<div class="cuerpo">
  <div class="otra_clase">No aplica
    <div class="mayusculas"> y en este si aplica</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por ayuda, perdon por mi forma de expresarme, quizas al no estar aun familiarizado en este campo, no me se expresar bien, lo lamento y gracias de nuevo!!

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo uso principalmente para indicar que el estilo lo quiero aplicar exclusivamente, por ejemplo a un elemento div que contenga dicha clase, Ejemplo:

```html
   <style>
        div.mayusculas {
          text-transform: uppercase;
       }
   </style>
    
    <div class="mayusculas">aquí aplica</div>
    <div>     
        <span class="mayusculas">aquí no aplica</span>
    </div>
```

Si por el contrario, si dejo un espacio en blanco estoy indicando que se trata de un selector anidado y por tanto el estilo se aplicara si la clase mayuscula esta anidada dentro de un div padre, Ejemplo:

```html
<style>
div .mayusculas {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>
<div>     
     <span class="mayusculas">aquí aplica</span>
</div>
<div class="mayusculas">aquí no aplica</div>
```

Comment: Buenas, bienvenido al sitio. ¿En qué difiere exactamente tu respuesta de las que ya se hicieron hace seis años?